# How to use `system()` to execute a command in the parent shell environment

Tags: c

Hey so basically when I run this code in the mac terminal: `export PS1="\[\033[36m\]\u\[\033[m\]@\[\033[32m\]\h:\[\033[33;1m\]\w\[\033[m\]\$"` it will change the color of the prompt.  I want that command in a `.c` source code file, then have that same **C** code execute it.

This is what I got:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


int main () {

    FILE *fp;

    fp = fopen("practice.txt", "w");

    if(!fp) return 1;

   fprintf(fp, "export PS1='\\[\\033[36m\\]\\u\\[\\033[m\\]@\\[\\033[32m\\]\\h:\\[\\033[33;1m\\]\\w\\[\\033[m\\]\\$'");

   system(fp);

   return(0);
}
```

But when it runs it does nothing. You can notice that when I copy the command over to the file I use double backslashes instead of the single ones because it's needed to print single backslashes to the file.

Comment: It's unclear whether "*text file*" refers to the **C** code above, or some other absent text file.

Comment: It refers to practice.txt in the code above

Comment: Thanks for the helpful clarification.   By design, (as a means of preventing all sorts of mischief), no program in _*nix_ can change any of the environmental variables of its parent shell.  Therefore it's *deliberately* not possible to do this with `system()`, so I'd recommend accepting *R Sahu*'s correct answer.

Answer (score 3):

When you execute the command

```
export PS1='\\[\\033[36m\\]\\u\\[\\033[m\\]@\\[\\033[32m\\]\\h:\\[\\033[33;1m\\]\\w\\[\\033[m\\]\\$'
```

using `system`, it changes the value of `PS1` in the shell that executes the command. It does not change the value of `PS1` in the shell that runs the program. Hence, you don't notice any difference.

I don't think you can accomplish what you are trying using `system`.

Answer (score 0):

Put the `PS=...` command in your `~/.bashrc`, then any new shell will have the desired prompt.

Comment: Do you know of a way I I can do it without manipulating any existing bash files but instead creating a text file with bash in it?

Comment: Not in **C**, but this would work:  `echo "PS='\\[\\033[36m\\]\\u\\[\\033[m\\]@\\[\\033[32m\\]\\h:\\[\\033[33;1m\\]\\w\\[\\033[m\\]\\$'" > ps.txt ; . ps.txt`.  Note the leading `.` in the 2nd command -- for info on that 2nd command type `help .` at a `bash` prompt.

Comment: Thank you a lot i tried it and it worked. I'm sure i can work with this. I appreciate it